# Matching values in two tables with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup, lookup

I have 2 Tables in Excel from SQL that I need to match.

**Table 1:**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

I would need to look up in Table 2 for date in column B where category is Relevant and return it into Table 1 where in Table 1 category is first visit.

I have tried all different formulas and it doesn't work.

Combination of INDEX() and MATCH() generally does not work.For example:

```
=INDEX(Table2B:B,MATCH(MAX(IF(Visitors number="AAAA",Order_Date)),Order_Date,0))
```

I get error.

The data set can be messy and too big, so I can not predefine that I am searching for second or third value.

Large with multiple criteria does not work either. I just get 0 or error. For example:

```
=LARGE(IF((Table2A2=Table2B:B)*(Table2B2>=Table1A:A);Table2C:C);1)
```

neither does SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SumProduct(LARGE((Table2A:A=Table1B2)*(Table2B2>=Table1A2*(Table2C:C);1))
```

Any kind advice of solution?

Thankful in advance.

Comment: I guess you want the result in Column D of table 1, but what is the result you are trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following ARRAY FORMULA:

```
=IF(C2="First Visit",INDEX(Table2!A:C,MATCH(A2&B2,Table2!B:B&Table2!A:A,0),3))
```

To make it work confirm it with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER to get the brackets {}:

```
{=IF(C2="First Visit",INDEX(Table2!A:C,MATCH(A2&B2,Table2!B:B&Table2!A:A,0),3))}
```

Comment: Dear Kaiser, Thank's for your answer. Sorry for delayed reply, just back from vacation.  I have tried your suggestion. Unfortunately it picks on the matching date in Table 1 and 2. While I need following: For row 1 in Table 1 , row 3 matches from Table 2. Row 2 and 3 in table 1 get  FALSE result, row 4 in Table 1 gets match on row 4 from Table 2. Row 5 in table 1 gets match on row 6 from Table 2 and so on. There is actually logic in Table 1 a 30 day period from first visit. So preferably that from table 2 within such 30 date period the most latest post/row matches back to Table 1.